What is kar mala?
Where can I find mentions of kar mala(one which only requires hand) and how should one do kar mala in case he does not have any other mala to do japa from
?

Hindi reference here is a video of Pt Narmdeshwar Shastri on his youtube channel.
Basically, starts counting from middle phalanx of ring finger, then Proximal phalanx, moves to little finger Proximal phalanx, moves upwards to Distal phalanx, counts Distal phalanx of all 4 fingers from there, count to 8 and then reimaging two phalanx of index counting to 10. Repeat again 10 times bringing count to 100.(only middle finger's middle and bottom phalanx are skipped)
For the last 8 skip the first and last from above sequence. Second hand is used to keep the count of 10.

